# Parallel processing in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I need to process Trades with same reference id sequentially but different reference id in parallel as they are independent. A Trade can have various events so same trade cannot be processed in parallel due to the fact that they modify the same instance of a Trade resulting in unexpected update.

I am using Spring integration framework to process the trade but task executor is processing all trades in parallel even if some of them share same reference id but different events. So kindly share code snippet to handle this scenario as i am unable to find any solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work, but I think it will.  In the method where you process a trade, synchronize on the intern'ed version of the id.  (I'm assuming id is a String.)

```
{
   String a = "some string";  // this is already intern'ed.
   String b = new String("some string");  // this is not.  You might have gotten the value from user, or whatever

   boolean b1 = a == b;  // false
   boolean b2 = a.equals(b);  // true
   boolean b3 = a.intern() == b.intern();  // Always true if b2 was true
}
```

So the point is, if you intern several strings, if two of them are the same value, you'll actually get the same string back.  So, in your runnable that you are handing to the executor,

```
public void run() {
    synchronize(trade.getId().intern()) {
        // process trade
    }
}
```

The only reason I'm not sure if it will work is because I'm not sure that you can synchronize on an internal version of the String, because that's like a static element.  I don't really see why not, but you should build an experiment to be sure.

Comment: That won't help with the order, though. I think you'd need to use something like a `Map<String, BlockingQueue<Request>>` and insert into the map from a single thread and process asynchronously downstream. There's nothing built into the framework for this use case. You could use something like Kafka as an interim medium where all records for the same key can be sent to the same partition.

Comment: I agree.  My solution might process the trades for a single ID in a different order than they arrived.  If there are a relatively small number of ID's, say, less than a few thousand, then the Map of BlockingQueues would work.  But if these are stock trades, then you'd waste too much memory on the tens or hundreds of thousands of BlockingQueues you have to make.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if `LockRegistry` can help you! So, you get a `Lock` for the "reference id" and don't let other threads to do the stuff with your particular `Trade` until you done in one thread.

You may use a `WhileLockedProcessor` for more cleaner code.